# How to parse json array with categories to make string categories?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I have a online json file with arrays with categories as follows:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Moda","howmuch":42}, (...)]
```

And there's 11 of these categories. Now what I need is to make that the app will download these arrays and put them to the Android app, so user can choose a category. It cannot be hardcoded to **strings.xml**.

Comment: have you search any tutorials or not?

Comment: Yes, I've searched for tutorials but there's nothing I could use for my project.

Comment: this link might helpful to you http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-populating-spinner-json-tutorial/

Comment: Please check my code , surely it will help you and for further you can just learn about parsing data from server concepts. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for this, 
On app start you save your this arrays into [shared Preferences](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm) or you can save to your [Sqlite database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
String result = "your result here";
        try {
            JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);
            if(data.length() > 0){
               for (int i =0; i < data.length(); i++){
                   String id = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
                   String name = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                   String howmuch = data.getJSONObject(i).getString("howmuch");
               }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```